# Which is most correct of these three phrases?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, sentence, writing

At the top part of the front page of my [trading journal](http://www.tradebench.com) website, I have a phrase that I don't know whether is correct or not. Here's what it says:

> Online trading journal software including trade planning and money management.
>       The smart way to plan, journal and learn from your trades
>       You get a structured approach to becoming more profitable. For free!

I am in doubt about the third line. Is any one or more of the following phrases correct? If so, which one(s) is (most) correct? If not, help in re-writing/re-wording the phrase would be highly appreciated.

1. You get a structured approach to become more profitable.
2. You get a structured approach to becoming more profitable.
3. You get a structured approach for becoming more profitable.

English is not my first language so I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Thank you for the sentence _I have a phrase that I don't know whether is correct or not._ It's not often one finds a violation of a Ross constraint in real life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You get a structured approach to becoming more profitable* is grammatically correct.

You might also consider,

*You get a structured approach enabling you to make more profitable trades*, if it is the trading software which is the focus.